# UIPageViewController multiple types for different indexes

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a class set up like this

```
class CardItemController: UIViewController,UIPageViewControllerDataSource
```

depending on the item index I need to use a different UIViewController Subclass like

private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> SuperUIPageController? {

```
if itemIndex < cards.count {
    if itemIndex == 0{
        let pageItemController = CardImagePageController()
        pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
        pageItemController.labelText = labelText
        //pageItemController.screenWidth = self.frame.width
        return pageItemController
    }else{
    let pageItemController = CardController()
    pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
    pageItemController.labelText = labelText
    //pageItemController.screenWidth = self.frame.width
    return pageItemController
    }
}

return nil
```

}

the CardController and CardImagePageController look like this

```
class CardController: SuperUIPageController {
class CardImagePageController: SuperUIPageController,UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
```

Whats the proper way to use different UIViewControllers depending on the index? Right now I am getting all kinds of errors such as
in CardImagePageController I am getting:

```
Type 'CardImagePageController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPageViewControllerDataSource'
```

when i have these methods in it

```
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {


func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> CardImageController? {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check example of UIPageViewController code here: https://github.com/dimpiax/UIPageViewControllerScrolling